# python Update global variable

Tags: python-3.x, global-variables

It is a set of short scripts with Python. However, I got a problem with updating a global variable.

```
# A.py

data = [[]]  # global data

def work1(list):
    data.append(list)

def work3():
    print (data)


# B.py
from A import work1

def work2():
    for each in input:
        work1(each)   # call work1


# C.py
from A import work3

def work4():
    work3()   # call work3
```

The "data" is a list of list which got long sentences.
And without "work2", "work4" will not called.

However, in "work3", "data" is always empty, not updated, being as '[[]]'
How can I fix this? (version of python is 3.4.4)

Comment: I'm not able to follow correctly. What should be your expected output and what are you getting? because calling just work3() will always return empty. from A import work3 will make copy of work3 in c.py.

Comment: There was a main function which calls work2() and work4(). Of course, there were some other working in those functions, however, I did not describe the details. The point is that the global data did not show some updated things to other modules. (it shows right updated data in its module, I mean where the global variable is declared)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a separate file for all your global values

```
#globals.py

class MyGlobals(object):
    data = [[]]  # global data

#c.py

from globals import MyGlobals

def work1(list):
    MyGlobals.data.append(list)

def work3():
    print (MyGlobals.data)

#b.py

from globals import MyGlobals
import c

input = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5]]

def work2():
   for each in input:
       C.work1(each)   # call work1

#a.py

from globals import MyGlobals
import c

def work4():
    c.work3()   # call work3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    work4();
```

## output

```
sh-4.3$ python a.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[[]]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
sh-4.3$
```

If you now want to update your global values, you can call work2() function in file b.py inside

```
#a.py 

from globals import MyGlobals
import c
import b

def work4():
    c.work3()   # call work3

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b.work2()
    work4()
```

## output

```
sh-4.3$ python a.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
[[], [1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5]]
```

There is an empty list in output because I'm not sure how you want to store them, since there is an existing empty list you are appending to in global data i.e data = [[]]

> To make it work as per your requirements. Put your global `list` in a file and import that file in every other module/file where you will be using it.

```
#a.py

data = [[]]  # global data

#b.py

import a

def work1(list):
    a.data.append(list)

def work3():
    print (a.data)

#c.py

import a
import b

input = [[1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5]]

def work2():
   for each in input:
      b.work1(each)   # call work1

#main.py

import a
import b
import c

def work4():
   b.work3()   # call work3

if __name__ == "__main__":
   c.work2()
   work4()
```

## output

```
sh-4.3$ python main.py                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
[[], [1, 3, 4], [2, 4, 4], [3, 4, 5]]       
sh-4.3$
```

Comment: Should I use "class" ? I  am not familiar with "class", and I just need a slot for data which can be accessed from other module, so I just declare a "list" as global. However, to fix this problem, I should use a class ?

Comment: Sorry, I totally forget to say thanks to you, really thanks for your help!

Comment: No, you don't need to use  class to make it work your way. wait for the updated answer

Comment: @jinho would you mind accepting the answer if your queries are resolved or if you need any further help you can always comment